# Why won't this docker file run on Windows 2016 10.0.14393?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I've created an asp.net core signalr project.  It builds great.  Image builds fine.  I publish to my private repository.  However, when I try to pull the image down onto a Windows 2016 server I get an error message: `docker : a Windows version 10.0.17134-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host`

I don't see where I'm targeting a specific platform, and the research that I've done seems like this should run

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./*.csproj ./EntityStatusChangeService/
RUN dotnet restore ./EntityStatusChangeService/EntityStatusChangeService.csproj

COPY ./. ./EntityStatusChangeService/
WORKDIR /app/EntityStatusChangeService
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out


FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/EntityStatusChangeService/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "EntityStatusChangeService.dll"]
```

Comment: at this location you can see the docker compatability chart (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility) for containers where it states that you are trying to run a newer image on an older container. you should update the container engine on the server so it will run the newer containers

Comment: The Docker version of the target machine is 18.09.1, build 20b67756d0.  Is there a way to build the image so that it will target the host OS?  The image is being built and pushed from a Windows 10 1809 machine.  Do I need to build the image on the same version of the host?

Comment: as far as i can tell from documentation i came across you would have to use  an older windows image that is supported for the container. this is the exact line from the link above "As we've been improving the Windows container features, we've had to make some changes that can affect compatibility. Older containers will run the same on newer hosts with Hyper-V isolation, and the same (older) kernel version will still be used. However, if you want to run a container based on a newer Windows build - it can only run on the newer host build."